# Vagrant gets segmentation fault when trying to add USB

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, vagrant

I got a simple Vagrantfile that uses archlinux/archlinux and is trying to access a usb that is connected to my host. When I do `vagrant up` I get an error like this:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant 
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
Command: ["showvminfo", "VAGRANT-ID", 
"--machinereadable"]
Stderr:
```

If I check it with `vboxmanage showvminfo VAGRANT-ID --machinereadable` I get a segmentation fault like this:

```
...
USBFilterManufacturer2=""
USBFilterProduct2=""
USBFilterRemote2=""
USBFilterSerialNumber2=""
[1]    9658 segmentation fault (core dumped)  vboxmanage showvminfo
VAGRANT-ID --machinereadable
```

The lines I use in my Vagrantfile that tries to access the USB.

```
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]
vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0', '--target', :id, '--name', 
'usb', '--vendorid', 'VENDOR-ID-HEX', '--productid', 'PRODUCT-ID-HEX']
```

My host OS is Fedora 29, Virtualbox version is 6.0 and Vagrant 2.2.3.

Something I've tried:

Removed the .vagrent folder and did vagrant up,

Added

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
Defaults:vagrant !requiretty
```

to the /etc/sudoers file

Use the

```
vboxmanage usbfilter add 0 --taget VAGRANT-ID --name usb 
--vendorid VENDOR-ID-HEX --productid PRODUCT-ID-HEX
```

(and that gave no error).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

It is not a Vagrant problem, it is a Virtualbox problem. As you can see, also a

```
vboxmanage showvminfo <uuid>
```

causes a segfault, which is visible on Linux. In my experiments, it was not visible in the Windows command line, but probably it can be debugged also there.

Vagrant, if it is used to manage Virtualbox containers, is essentially a big ruby script around `vboxmanage`. It can detect that `vboxmanage` fails by its unordinary exit code, but it doesn't know too much from its reason.

The bug is in the `vboxmanage` binary, not in one of the internal virtualbox libraries what it is using.

The problem can be found in the public VirtualBox bugtracker [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18341).

A fix was implemented with test build 128880, but it wasn't released yet. Until we don't have a new release, we need to use the test build.

If the test build - as an internal development version - doesn't work, there is an option to extract only `vboxmanage` from that, and using it with the latest stable. This scenario worked for me both on Windows and Linux.

Hopefully a release will happen soon.